# Is snap store a surplus now that ubuntu software center contains snaps?

Tags: software-center, snap

So I was wondering, Ubuntu Software Center (USC) allows downloading snaps now (I'm assuming it's somewhat of a new feature).
If that so, does snap store have any uniqueness? Does it offer anything that USC don't?
i.e. Does USC maps any app that snap store does? if not why not?
personally I like the idea of a single centralized repository and can see some major pros for it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Snap Store will continue to be maintained for other distros that don't have an Ubuntu Software equivalent.

You can use Snap Store with Ubuntu as much as you like...though it's functionality is indeed duplicated by the Ubuntu Software application.